# Why PowerShell presents double-hop issue with Linux as 3rd computer

Tags: powershell, security

I'm pretty aware of the `Double Hop` security feature of Windows. However why it does apply when trying to connect to a 3rd computer that is Linux based and whose authentication is based on Private Key; so not Kerberos.

Scenario:

```
Computer1 (Win10) --> Computer2 (Server 2019 - PS7) --> Computer3 (Ubuntu Linux - PS6.1.6)
```

Working well from `Computer1 --> Computer3` using SSH and Private Key:

```
Invoke-Command -HostName computer3 -Command {hostname} -UserName user -KeyFilePath C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Not working well via `Computer2`:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName computer2 -ConfigurationName PowerShell.7.0.0
[computer2]: PS C:\> Invoke-Command -HostName computer3 -Command {hostname} -UserName user -KeyFilePath C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa
(never executes, remains waiting forever)
```

Note: if I RDP to Computer2 then the above-mentioned command works well; which sounds strange because credentials used to RDP to Computer2 are not the same being used to connect to Computer3.

Comment: So, you are making a request via PowerShell from host1 to host2, which is not a hop at all, but a direct request from host1 to host2, then trying to hop from host2 to Linux, so really this is 3 hops from your initial PS session execution. You then say, RDP to host2 then make a call to Linux?  Which is not a hop at all, it is a direct request from host2 to Linux, or are you saying, you are making a session request to host1 from your host, than making a call from host1 to host2 then trying to make a request from host2 to Linux? Why woudl you think that would work, especially across domains?

Comment: And you are coming from a Win10 box running PSv5x, then to WS2019 using PS7 to Linux using SSH? Really? I am seriously taken aback relative to the use case here. Why not just put PSv7 on the Win10 host and make the request to Linux?

Comment: @postanote I'm logged into `computer1`, which is a Win10 host with PS7.0. The first hop `computer1 --> computer2` is Kerberos-based because they are domain-joined computers. It is therefore clear that my credentials are not placed in `computer2`. However the authentication `computer2 --> computer3` is not using my credentials, but instead a SSH Private Key. To my knowledge the [double-hop problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7) should not apply.

Comment: I get that, but you cannot remote to any system that does not have remoting enabled. [PS Remoting over SSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7) You are literally trying to change the user auth and ops (WinRM to SSH) context of a given session to a new session. PowerShell will only run in the context of the user who started it. If you are using PSv7 on Win 10, why go to WS2K19, to get to Linux? If Linux is in the same domain as WIn10, then why not go directly to it? If Linux is not in the domain that's a catch22

Comment: @postanote indeed Linux machine is not in the domain, just network reachable. Reason why `computer1 --> computer3` is not possible is because the real architecture is a [PowerShell Azure Functions with Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-hybrid-powershell) using the `Win2019` as the computer running the Hybrid Manager (only Windows supported) and I need to grab some data placed on `computer3` by SSH. I don't control `computer3` and is not really only one `computer3` but many.

Comment: As the connection from `computer2 --> computer3` is not interactive with `Enter-PSSession` but instead an `Invoke-Command`, I suspect this problem is not related to double-hop. I've read somewhere in the past that in Windows, remote admin users get different 'OS properties' and they behave a bit different. Maybe this is related to the `$host`:

`PS C:\> $host.name #Output: ConsoleHost`

`PS C:\> invoke-command -ComputerName computer2 -ScriptBlock {$host.name} #Output: ServerRemoteHost`